# Java TLS Session Reuse after closed connection

Tags: java, ssl, session

I have a Java TLS client that can send a series of requests to a server, each followed by a response from the server.

However, there are many different servers.  Some are "multi-message" servers that keep a connection open after the first request, so that subsequent requests can be sent over the first connection.  Others are "single-message" servers that close the connection after each message and so a new connection is required for subsequent messages.  There is no a priori way for the client to know what type of server it is talking to, nor to fix the servers.

It is very desirable for single-message servers to be able to resume a session without the full handshake.

My original client code just tried to send subsequent requests down the same connection.  If that failed it just opened a new connection to the server.  It could thus handle both single and multi-message servers.

However, the failure when sending the second message to single-message servers seems to kill the session resumption.

My dirty work around is to notice if a message fails and then assume that it is talking to a single-message server, in which case the client then explicitly closes the socket after each response has been received.  This enables subsequent connections to resume sessions.

But there has to be a better way.  Testing for isInputShutdown or isConnected does not help, unsurprisingly, as there are timing issues.  The connection failure for single-message server actually happens during the read of the response, after the write of the request, presumably due to buffering.

Any ideas much appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Your initial solution is correct in the case of plaintext: you will get an `IOException: connection reset by peer` when sending the second message, and you can just recover accordingly by reconnecting.

However in the TLS case it won't work, as you will not get `IOException: connection reset by peer` but a `SocketException`, due to a fatal TLS `unexpected_message` alert. [RFC 2246 #7.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) states:

> Alert messages with a level of fatal result
>      in the immediate termination of the connection. In this case, other
>      connections corresponding to the session may continue, but *the
>      session identifier must be invalidated*, preventing the failed session
>      from being used to establish new connections.

[my emphasis], because the failed session is now deemed insecure, and

> unexpected_message
>
> An inappropriate message was received. This alert is always fatal
>          and should never be observed in communication between proper
>          implementations.

Your second solution seems appropriate to me.

NB:

- `isInputShutdown()` can never be true, as you can't call `shutdownInput()` on an SSLSocket.
- `isConnected()` will never be false once the socket has been connected.
- Both tell you about the state of your socket, not of the connection, so even trying them was futile. And it has nothing to do with 'timing issues'.